# In PostgreSQL, How to get all users who are logged into the session and also get their IP address and Query whenever they access databse?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using **PostgreSQL**. Nearly five people will be using the same database. I want to get the data about ***who are running which query*** both in *HeidiSQL tool* and *Webapplication*.
I tried using ***`pg_stat_activity`*** table to get the details. But it returns only one row per IP, which is the corresponding machine's query details.

Comment: This is unclear. Are you talking about five database connections? Or about five people using an application that accesses a database? You need superuser privileges to see information about other user's sessions in `pg_stat_activity`.

Comment: would not OP still see rows with `<insufficient privilege>` instead of queries and such?.. If he sees only his session - others are not connected?..

Comment: Right. But maybe the OP sees these rows as "non-rows". Lacking query output we cannot say much.

Comment: guys - what is the reason to upvote this question? I don't understand how such questions get upvoted so fast.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Five people using an application that accesses a database

Comment: Then you cannot get the information from the database - only your application can know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to log who was connected use 
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-CONNECTIONS

to log what statements were used, use 
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-STATEMENT

`pg_stat_activity` shows connected session only:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html

> One row per server process, showing information related to the current
>   activity of that process, such as state and current query.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-ACTIVITY-VIEW

you might also be interested in https://github.com/pgaudit/pgaudit and https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgstatstatements.html